# Jquery - Multiple blur event and output value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field to insert user identity number(NRIC). After user input the number and looses focus, it will auto calculate the number and will give the value of **date of birth** and also user's **age**.

If I have multiple inputs for the NRIC number, how do I want to set it to get the selected field on blur function and get the value for **dob** and **age** base on the selected blur input? Below are the example that I did,

```js
$(".ic_no").blur(function(){
 var d = new Date();
 var n = d.getFullYear();
    
 //Get value of NRIC No. eg: 870505115515 
 var ic_no = $("#ic_no").val();
 var dob = ic_no.substr(0, 6); //870505 
 var y = parseInt(dob.substr(0, 2)); //87 
    
 //Add value to get full year base on y value
 if (y > 20) {
  yearFull = "19" + y; 
 } else {
  yearFull = parseInt("20" + dob.substr(0, 2));
 }

 var m = dob.substr(2, 2); //05(Month)
 var d = dob.substr(4, 2); //05(Day)
 var f = yearFull + "-" + m + "-" + d;
  
 if (ic_no) { 
  $("#dob").val(f);

  if (yearFull > n) {
   var age = yearFull - n; 
  } else {
   var age = n - yearFull;  
  }

  if (age < 1) {
   age += 1; 
  }
   
  $("#age").val(age);
 }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Item 1: 
<div class="form-group">
 <input type="text" name="ic_no[]" class="ic_no" id="ic_no" placeholder="NRIC No.">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <input type="date" name="dob[]" id="dob" class="form-control dob">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <input type="text" name="age[]" id="age" class="form-control age"  placeholder="Age">
</div>

<br>

Item 2:
<div class="form-group">
 <input type="text" name="ic_no[]" class="ic_no" id="ic_no" placeholder="NRIC No.">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <input type="date" name="dob[]" id="dob" class="form-control dob">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <input type="text" name="age[]" id="age" class="form-control age"  placeholder="Age">
</div>
```

Base on the code, only `Item 1` gets the value.

Comment: Can you please explain you problem more briefly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same **id** for all your elements. Id's should be unique.

What I've done with your code is to access the elements from the one that has fired the blur event.

Then I've enclosed every item in a "main" container so I can access the other input by parent().parent().find()...

That way is a bit ugly in my opinion, but with your code is the only solution that comes to my mind!

Check it out and try not to use the same id for more than one element.

Cheers!

```js
$(".ic_no").blur(function(event){
 var active_element = $(event.target);
 var d = new Date();
 var n = d.getFullYear();
    
 //Get value of NRIC No. eg: 870505115515 
 var ic_no = $(active_element).val();
 var dob = ic_no.substr(0, 6); //870505 
 var y = parseInt(dob.substr(0, 2)); //87 
    
 //Add value to get full year base on y value
 if (y > 20) {
  yearFull = "19" + y; 
 } else {
  yearFull = parseInt("20" + dob.substr(0, 2));
 }

 var m = dob.substr(2, 2); //05(Month)
 var d = dob.substr(4, 2); //05(Day)
 var f = yearFull + "-" + m + "-" + d;
  
 if (ic_no) {
  $(active_element).parent().parent().find("#dob").val(f);

  if (yearFull > n) {
   var age = yearFull - n; 
  } else {
   var age = n - yearFull;  
  }

  if (age < 1) {
   age += 1; 
  }
   
  $(active_element).parent().parent().find("#age").val(age);
 }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Item 1: 
<div class="item">
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" name="ic_no[]" class="ic_no" id="ic_no" placeholder="NRIC No.">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="date" name="dob[]" id="dob" class="form-control dob">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" name="age[]" id="age" class="form-control age"  placeholder="Age">
  </div></div>
<br>

Item 2:
<div class="item">
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" name="ic_no[]" class="ic_no" id="ic_no" placeholder="NRIC No.">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="date" name="dob[]" id="dob" class="form-control dob">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" name="age[]" id="age" class="form-control age"  placeholder="Age">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. May I know for the parent(), the first parent will be the item class and the second is the div for the input. Is it correct?

Comment: $(active_element) would be your input, so the first parent() refers to the parent div with class "form-group", and the second parent() refers to the div with the class "item". I hope it helps. If you think my answer solved your question, you should check the green tick! cheers :)